# Android Firebase database custom username login not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have tried to login using Google Firebase database using custom username but it is not working.

I need how to get username and password for retrieving username and
password for login:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //private Toolbar toolbar;
    private EditText username1, password2;
    private Button buttonlogin;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
//    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_login );

        username1 = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.username1 );
        password2 = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.password2 );
        buttonlogin = (Button) findViewById ( R.id.buttonlogin );
//        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ( "Usres" );
//        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance ();

        buttonlogin.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                login ();
            }
        } );
    }



    private void login() {
        final String Username = username1.getText ().toString ().trim ();
        final String Password = password2.getText ().toString ().trim ();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ( "Usres" );

        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Artist artist = dataSnapshot.getValue(Artist.class);
                if (artist.username.equals(Username) && artist.password.equals(Password)) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserLogin.class));
                } else if (Username.equals("Crazy") && Password.equals("Tasty")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Admin.class));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username and Password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

[image: Database]

The above shown is the database that I have used in `Firebase` and what I want is not happening.

While am trying to login application immediately terminate and exit
    application

Comment: please, told us what you've tried

Comment: Please can you post your database structure as we are not going to have permission to view your data through the console.

Comment: Also is there a reason you're not using the standard Firebase authentication module?

Comment: have a look at this helper class. 
https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Firebase-Helper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/inc/droidflick/firebasetutorial/firebasenetwork/FireBaseHelper.java

Comment: post your database structure.

Comment: Pretty sure you've a typo here: `"Usres"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you just have to change the following line of code:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ( "Usres" );
```

to

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
```

As I see in your database schema, your user node is named `Users` and not `Usres`.

Comment: am tried above code but not working